# Calculating sha256 of S3 StreamingBody differs from sha256sum returned checksum

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hash, boto3

So the gist is: I am using boto3 to get_object from S3. The response body contains a "StreamingBody" object. When I calculate the sha256 sum of it like this:

```
sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
for line in file_to_extract_from.iter_lines():
    sha256.update(line)

print("sha256: {0}".format(sha256.hexdigest()))
```

It returns `16aba5393ad72c0041f5600ad3c2c52ec437a2f0c7fc08fadfc3c0fe9641d7a3`

However, when I calculate it using my Linux inbuilt sha256sum, it returns `b7f1ee9373416a49835747455ec4d287bcccc5a4bf8c38156483d46b35ce4dbd` instead. I wonder what is wrong with my configuration?

EDIT: After asking this question I realised that S3 is only returning me the content of the file and its calculating the hash based on that, where as on my linux I'm calculating the hash for the whole file. Is there a way to calculate a hash for the whole file from S3?

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid. My file on my linux system had a new blank line at the end of the file, which AWS seems to overwrite. Once I removed the blank line from my local machine, I ended up getting the correct checksum.